# Spring method requires creating new anonymous instance and disallows use of existing instance

Tags: java, spring

I was following the Getting Started example of using the Spring Framework found [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start). My question deals specifically with the code located under the Application class defined on the page:

```all
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageService() {
            public String getMessage() {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = 
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
        printer.printMessage();
    }
}
```

Specifically, this part here:

```all
    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageService() {
            public String getMessage() {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        };
    }
```

This method creates a new anonymous MessageService object on-the-fly. On my end, I wanted to create a single instance, and just have the *mockMessageService* method return that single instance (as has been my practice for years). However, when replacing that method with the following, I am met with a "service is null" output.

```all
    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return messageService;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String message = "Hello World!";
        final MessageService messageService = new MockMessageService(message);
        final Application app = new Application();
        app.messageService = messageService;

        final ApplicationContext context =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        final MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
        if (printer == null) {
            System.out.println("printer is null");
            return;
        }
        if (printer.getService() == null) {
            System.out.println("service is null");
            return;
        }
        if (printer.getService().getMessage() == null) {
            System.out.println("service message is null");
            return;
        }
        printer.printMessage();
    }

    private MessageService messageService;
```

So ultimately my question is, why am I prohibited from using one single instance of the class, or put differently, why is it required to create a new instance every time the method is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is not using your `app` instance it is creating its own.  Note you pass spring the `Application.class`, it has no knowledge of your `app` instance.  If you change your `private MessageService messageService` instance member to `static` you should get what you want.

Comment: I should have realized as much when I saw that the _app_ variable wasn't being used anywhere. I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks for your help. It makes much more sense now (or common-sense).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a single instance than mark the scope of the object as singleton you would get a single instance of the object. e.g.

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
```

But since you have not specified anything singleton is the default scope